# Django : How to send notification to admin on a specific user activity?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin

I'm building a website that needs sending a notification to the admin when a request for help happens, It doesn't need to be literally a notification, it may b email in the admin panel or so, 
Thanks ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use signals. [django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/)

When the request happens - invoke a signal from server and save new data that you wish.

Another easy and great example:
[simpleisbetterthancomplex](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html)

Maybe create history module to store the help request event.